# Page curl animation to Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, page-curl

I want to give page curl effect when changing `Layout`, had refered [**Harism Pagecurl**](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) dig it so came to know its giving effect to pre-generated views(Bitmaps) but by requirement is as follows....

1. Layout can be complex contains various controls(Button, Textview etc.).
2. I can able to click Button, TextView and can handle its events.
3. Able to swipe layout with curl effect when I touch area which doesn't contain any control.

Any idea or workaround are welcome, its tricky.